# Thread raising event gets blocked by handlers?

Tags: c#, c++, event-handling, multithreading, blocking

I am raising an event from managed C++ which is handled by a C# app.
Is the C# event handler executed on the same thread it was raised from C++ ??

In other words, Is raising event blocking for C++ until it is completely handled by C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event handler invocation is synchronous by default in .NET, and since your code is both Managed C++ and C#, it is all ".NET".

If you wish your event handlers to function asynchronously, you could simply attach a handler on the C# side that either starts another `Thread` to do the work, drops a worker into `ThreadPool`, or invokes another method to handle the work asynchronously via a `Delegate` using [asynchronous programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb(VS.71).aspx). The handler would then return quickly, allowing the C# work to execute in the background while the MC++ code can continue invoking other listeners of the event.

Make sure that if you do execute the code that actually handles the event asynchronously, that the C++ code does not expect data in the event arguments to be modified by the handlers. This would be the case if something like [CancelEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.aspx) were used.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Extra text to get around the length limit :)

And I had to pass an "I'm Human" test!

Comment: and this applies if I was raising and handling both in C#??

Comment: In purely managed DLLs yea it's all the same - regardless of language.  I'm not sure what it would be like if it was an unmanaged event.